# Activate Entry Box from Listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to create a GUI to collect three inputs from a user, where the first input has two options (based on a Listbox), like the image below (where the option "NACA" is selected):

[image]

The problem is with the Listbox. I guess the options are overlapping each other. For example, If I select the NACA option (image above), and then I select the .txt option, some part of the NACA label remains:

[image]

And of course, just the labels are appearing, not the entry_boxes to type inside (if I delete the part of the listBox, the entry_boxes of the last two input appers, so I really guess the problem is with the ListBox)

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300') 
root.resizable(0, 0)



menu_inicial = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
menu_inicial.pack()


def naca_box():
    naca_entry_box = tk.Entry(menu_inicial)
    menu_inicial.create_window(200, 30, window=naca_entry_box)
    naca_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter NACA:")
    naca_label.pack()
    naca_label.place(x=50, y = 50)
    
def txt_box():
    txt_entry_box = tk.Entry(menu_inicial)
    menu_inicial.create_window(200, 30, window=txt_entry_box)
    txt_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter .txt:")
    txt_label.pack()
    txt_label.place(x=50, y = 50)
    
    
def aoa_box():
    aoa_entry_box = tk.Entry(root)
    menu_inicial.create_window(200, 60, window=aoa_entry_box)
    aoa_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter AoA (º):")
    aoa_label.pack()
    aoa_label.place(x=50, y = 80)
    
    
def panel_box():
    panel_entry_box = tk.Entry(root)
    menu_inicial.create_window(200, 90, window=panel_entry_box)
    panel_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Nº Panels:")
    panel_label.pack()
    panel_label.place(x=40, y = 110)


def update_box(*args):
    selection = box_list.curselection() 
    lb_value.set(options[selection[0]] ) 
    
    if selection[0] == 0:
        naca_box()
    else:
        txt_box()

options = ['NACA', '.txt']

listCon = tk.StringVar(value=options)
box_list = tk.Listbox(menu_inicial, listvariable=listCon, width=10, height=2, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
box_list.grid(row=0, column=0)
box_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', update_box)

lb_value=tk.StringVar()

aoa_box()
panel_box()


root.mainloop()
```

How can I proceed with this? Is a problem with the "IF" statement to choose the options ? (I don't know if this is the best what to do this...)

Comment: Try using the same label for both, just change the text depending on the selection.

Comment: You can make a widget invisible by calling its [`pack_forget()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) method. It doesn't destroy it and it can be re-shown later with another call to `pack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while you clicking button each time,
you are creating label each time,
if you want to change the text in the label you created,use 'config()'

change your code like this,

```
sample_label=tk.Label(root)
sample_label.place(x=50, y = 50)

def naca_box():
    naca_entry_box = tk.Entry(menu_inicial)
    menu_inicial.create_window(200, 30, window=naca_entry_box)
    sample_label.config(text="Enter NACA:")

    
def txt_box():
    txt_entry_box = tk.Entry(menu_inicial)
    menu_inicial.create_window(200, 30, window=txt_entry_box)
    sample_label.config(text="Enter .txt:")
```